# How to make MS SQL select on this

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have MS SQL database table like this

TableA

```
+----+-----------+--------+
|ID  | Table2_FK |  Value |
+----+-----------+--------+
|1   | 7         |  X     |
|2   | 7         |  Y     |
|3   | 8         |  X     |
|4   | 8         |  Z     |
|5   | 9         |  W     |
|6   | 9         |  M     |
|5   | 10        |  X     |
|6   | 10        |  Z     |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

I want to make query to get list of Table2_FKs if I pass X and Z in query for Values. In this example 8 and 10 is the result

It can be more than 2 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select table2_fk
from t
where value in ('X', 'Z')
group by table2_fk
having count(*) = 2;
```

If the values can be duplicated for a key value, then use `count(distinct value) = 2`.  The "2" is the number of values in the `IN` list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct Table2_FK
  from TableA
 where value in ('X','Z');
```

Comment: In that case I will get all Table2_FKs where X is value and where Z is value.
I want ones that X and Z is value and Table2_FK are the same. So in this example 8 and 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use query as below:

```
Select distinct table2_fk from (
   Select *, Ct = count(id) over (partition by table2_fk) from yourtable 
  ) a
  Where a.[Value] in ('X','Z') and a.Ct >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like below

```
select 
   distinct Table2_FK 
from TableA a 
where exists (
select 1 1 from TableA b where b.value ='X' and a.Table2_FK =b.Table2_FK
)
and exists (
select 1 1 from TableA c where c.value ='Z' and a.Table2_FK =c.Table2_FK
)
```